# Вывод сообщений в RichTextBox из всех участков программы

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, ооп, winforms

Допустим у меня есть WFA приложение и я хочу, что бы программа выводила сообщения из определенных участков программы в определенных RichTextBox .

Как это сделать грамотно/красиво?

Сейчас у меня функции, которые должны выводить сообщения, обязательно имеют в качестве параметра объект RichTextBox.

Правильный ли такой подход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем ваш подход не правильный, функции не должны в общем случае жестко привязываться к UI. Если речь о сообщениях то нужно генерировать события (events), а класс который отвечает за вывод сообщений будет подписан на эти события.

Comment: А можно пример, как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: Изучай event driven programming - простецкий пример http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/subhendude/event-driven-programming-in-C-Sharp/